# Conversion from string to Ice::ByteSeq

Tags: c++, ice

I gotta question about Ice in C++. One of my methods requires that I pass in a `Ice::ByteSeq`. I would like to build this `ByteSeq` from a string. How is this conversion possible?

I tried the options below.

```
Ice::ByteSeq("bytes")        // Invalid conversion to unsigned int
Ice::ByteSeq((byte*)"bytes") // Invalid conversion from byte* to unsigned int
(Ice::ByteSeq)"bytes"        // Invalid conversion from const char& to unsigned int
(Ice::ByteSeq)(unsigned int)atoi("bytes") // Blank (obviously, why did I try this?)
```

How can I make this happen?

**EDIT**

`"bytes"` is a placeholder value. My actualy string is non-numeric text information.

Comment: how is `Ice::ByteSeq` defined ?

Comment: do you need to pass a string which will be converted to a byte array?

Comment: @Raxvan I wish I could figure that out. I kinda hate ZeroC right now. GMasucci I need a string to Ice::ByteSeq conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [header](https://github.com/vervic/Ice-3.4.2/blob/master/include/Ice/BuiltinSequences.h), `ByteSeq` is an alias for `vector<Byte>`. You can initialise that from a `std::string` in the usual way

```
std::string s = "whatever";
Ice::ByteSeq bs(s.begin(), s.end());
```

or from a string literal with a bit more flappery, such as

```
template <size_t N>
Ice::ByteSeq byteseq_from_literal(char (&s)[N]) {
    return Ice::ByteSeq(s, s+N-1); // assuming you don't want to include the terminator
}

Ice::ByteSeq bs = byteseq_from_literal("whatever");
```

Comment: Well... This works! I don't know why I couldn't find that `.h` file. I'm not that impressed with Ice so far. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there,

```
Ice::ByteSeq((unsigned int)atoi("bytes"));
```

should do it

Assuming your Ice::ByteSeq has a constructor that takes unsigned int

To split this down, it's basically doing

```
int num = atoi("12345"); // num = (int) 12345 
unsigned int num2 = (unsigned int)num;  // num2 = (unsigned int) 12345
Ice::ByteSeq(num2);
```

Comment: This almost works, the problem is that the `atoi` command makes my string nothing, since it is characters instead of numbers.

Comment: What does your string actually contain, and what does the `Ice::ByteSeq` constructor expect to receive?

Comment: It's text. Like `"command!"` and I have no idea what `Ice::ByteSeq` expects, it is not in ZeroC's documentation.

Comment: You must have a header file somewhere - if you're in Visual C++ right click on ByteSeq in your editor and go to definition, and find how the constructor is defined

Comment: I'm currently using gedit. So no, not using Visual C++. I am trying to trace it back to the source, but Ice has weird inclusions.

Comment: you can always bypass the `Ice::ByteSeq` step and go straight to generating the actual byte sequence yourself, it appears that the `Ice::ByteSeq` is internally a `vector` of `unsigned char`

Answer (score 0):

If `Ice::ByteSeq` is simply a vector of bytes you can convert a string to a vector of bytes by doing a variation of the following:

```
std::string str = "Hello World";
std::vector<char> bytes(str.begin(), str.end());
```

The implementation of `Ice::Byte` is an `unsigned char` just change the standard code I posted from:

```
std::vector<char> bytes(str.begin(), str.end());
```

to

```
std::vector<unsigned char> bytes(str.begin(), str.end());
```

and the generated vector should be directly compatible with an `Ice::ByteSeq`

**sample code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Hello World";
    std::vector<unsigned char> bytes(str.begin(), str.end());
    cout << str << endl; 

    for(int i=0; i < bytes.size(); i++)
        std::cout << bytes[i] << '\n';
   return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps:)